# Galois representation with infinite image but finite image everywhere locally

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, motives, profinite-groups, p-adic-hodge-theory

Fix a prime $l$. Let $\phi:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_l)$ be a semisimple continuous representation. Assume $\phi$ has finite image when restricted to $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ for any $p$ (including $p=l$). Can $\phi$ have infinite image?

Since $\phi$ is de Rham at $l$, to have infinite image it must be ramified at infinitely many places. Examples of semisimple infinitely ramified Galois representations were constructed in [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0003241) of Ramakrishna (note that the ramified primes [necessarily](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011272) have zero density).

Comment: I think $\phi$ can have infinite image, cf. Corollary 13 of [Khare, C., Larsen, M., & Ramakrishna, R. (2005). Constructing semisimple p-adic Galois representations with prescribed properties. American Journal of Mathematics, 127(4), 709-734.]